# time taken by for loop with (2^32-1) or (2^64-1) or more is same

Tags: c

I calculated the time taken by a for loop `for (i=0; i<4294967295;i++)` in the C language. Surprising, it is very short (80-88 ns) on my node (speed 1600Mhz). Later, I tried to run the two for loop one above the other (i.e. `for(j=0; j<4294967295;j++)` `for(i=0; i<4294967295;i++)`. Surprisingly, this time is also short and same (i.e., 80ns). Could somebody explain me, why the time too low while running so many `i++` in the for loop. Additionally, when I run two or three for loops, why the time taken by these many `i++` is same. Many thanks in advance for a reply!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your loop is without side-effects, probably the compiler is optimizing it away completely. To trick the compiler into generating the loop anyway a common trick is to insert an `asm nop` inside the loop (compilers usually don't mess with hand-inserted assembly, and its cost is negligible).

Comment: Thanks Matteo for your response! Could you please explain what do you mean by side-effects?

Comment: @SachinSharma: changes to the state of the program that remain "visible" after the loop ended. IOW: if the output of your program would be the same with or without the loop the compiler is allowed to omit it completely.

Answer (score 2):

I did an experiment with gcc and here is my results. Basically as you can see below in my post compiler removes empty/idle loops in high optimization mode.

**Source file:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<1024; i++);
  return 0;
}
```

**Compilation with no optimization:**

```
gcc -O0 main.c
```

**Program dissasembly with no optimization:**

```
00000000004004ed <main>:
  4004ed:   55                      push   %rbp
  4004ee:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4004f1:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
  4004f8:   eb 04                   jmp    4004fe <main+0x11>
  4004fa:   83 45 fc 01             addl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
  4004fe:   81 7d fc ff 03 00 00    cmpl   $0x3ff,-0x4(%rbp)
  400505:   7e f3                   jle    4004fa <main+0xd>
  400507:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  40050c:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  40050d:   c3                      retq   
  40050e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

**Compilation with maximum optimization level:**

```
gcc -O3 main.c
```

**Program dissasembly with maximum optimization level:**

```
0000000000400400 <main>:
  400400:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400402:   c3                      retq
```

**You can dissasembly the program with the following command line tool:**

```
objdump -d a.out
```

---

**Besides you can always disable compiler optimization for any function you want with following compiler directives.**

Under GCC compiler you can turn off optimization for selected functions manually   with compiler directives like in the example below.

```
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")
static void your_not_optimized_function() {
    // your code
}
#pragma GCC pop_options
```

Under VC compiler you can turn off optimization for selected functions manually with compiler directives like in the example below.

```
#pragma optimize( "", off )
static void your_not_optimized_function() {
    // your code
}
#pragma optimize( "", on )
```

Comment: I like this answer. When checking the performance of optimized code, it's always a good idea to check the assembly code to see how the compiler implemented the code. In fact, for micro-optimizations, looking at the assembly can sometimes be more informative than running timing measurements.

Comment: As stated above, the unoptimized build tells you nothing about the "real world". In particular, the generated assembly here is a completely naive translation of the original C code, keeping the loop index on the stack for no reason, performing the check before entering the loop at start even if it's not needed and so on. If you do an optimized build forcing the compiler to keep the loop (inserting an `asm("nop");` in the loop body) you get http://pastebin.com/XcJ9euBK.

Comment: There you can see that the compiler avoided completely the stack setup, just used `eax` for the loop variable (=no memory accesses), reversed the loop indexing (which isn't used anyway) to avoid a `cmp` before the `jne`, avoided the "jump to the check at end" required to mimic the general `for` semantics of C and added a "long `nop`" to align the loop start in memory at 8 bytes for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent your loops from being optimized out by the compiler, you need to do something unpredictable inside the loops. The easiest thing to do is call a random number generator, like this

```
srand(time(NULL));
int total = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
    for ( int j = 0; j < 1000; j++ )
       total += rand();
printf( "%d\n", total );
```

Note that you also have to do something with the results, e.g. print the total. Otherwise, the compiler can still optimize out the loops.

Comment: Notice however that here you are measuring also the time spent in `rand` (which I expect to be way more significant than the cost of the two loops).

Comment: Thanks for clarification!! It really cleared my doubt!!

Comment: @SachinSharma  You're welcome, feel free to accept Matteo's answer as the correct answer, since I was just adding a little to that answer :)

Comment: You don't state what compiler you're using but most (all?) compilers have ways to turn off compile-time optimization. For example, if you're using `gcc` you can specify the `-O0` flag on the compile command, e.g. `gcc -O0 yourprogram.c`. Try disabling all optimizations and then run your program, although I suggest limiting the upper bound to something reasonable like 1000000. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis: yep, but timing unoptimized code makes no sense at all (the compiler outputs ridiculously inefficient code just to aid debugging - `gcc` at -O0 continues to move stuff uselessly between the stack and the registers).

Comment: @MatteoItalia - agreed. One is caught between the Scylla of timing unoptimized code, and the Charybdis of time non-existent code. Humph. I say that all high-level languages should be banned, and only assembler should be allowed. (And I'm old enough to remember coding on machines where we didn't even have an assembler, and had to know the opcodes by heart. Ah, great days, *great* days... :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis: probably the Right Thing™ is to avoid this kind of microbenchmarks completely, since, besides being difficult to set up, they tell you nothing about what the compiler (and the processor) do in the real scenarios you are interested in, where using an extra register, having a potentially aliased pointer, not inlining a function or not being able to vectorize a loop can actually kill the performance of an algorithm... As for the "assembly-only policy", that could be a solution... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

At least in the case of Microsoft compilers, you can use volatile on a variable to prevent the compiler from optimizing the loop away, but this will force the variable to be in memory instead of a register. You could also write a small test loop in assembler, sort of a very simple processor benchmark.

In a more realistic situation, where the loop is actually doing something, it shouldn't get optimized away and you'll be able to time it.